# Prevent file copying of Android files by smartswitch and similar apps

Tags: android

For security I need to prevent my app files being copied by Samsung Smartswitch and similar apps used when transferring data to a new phone.
One problem is the transfer resets all the last modified times which would normally only be changed by the app.  This causes issues such as older file versions from the source device overwriting newer versions in the cloud.

The files are under the Application installation folder.

Comment: What is the Applucation installation folder?

Comment: The folder where the application is installed e.g. /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/ 
Android has symbolic links to the actual sandboxed filestore location so there can be other pathnames to the same location such as <USER>/<APPNAME>

Comment: No your app is not installed in the folder you mentioned.  The files created by your app can be there. The app.apk is somewhere else where you cannot see it on a not rooted device.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that, I should have written "The folder where the application data is installed"

Comment: No. Wrong too. There will not be application data installed there. The folder you mentioned is an app private folder where the app can create files at runtime. Nothing happens when the app is installed.